# scilab, passing parameters to the function and changing variable type

Tags: scilab

I'm trying to build a GUI to output plots for control system design when input parameters of transfer function.I got some problems on passing parameters to the function and changing variable type.

I've got a stucture with examples of simulation parameters:

```
param = [];
param.parameter = "s";
param.dom = "c";       //domain(c for continuous, d for discrete)
param.num = 1;          //numerator  of transfer function
param.den = "(s+1)^3";  //denominator 
param.fmin = 0.01;     //min freq of the plot
param.fmax = 100;      //max freq
```

and a function to plot the graphs:

```
// display function
function displayProblem(param)
    parameter = param.parameter;
    dom = param.dom;
    num = param.num;
    den = param.den;
    fmin = param.fmin;
    fmax = param.fmax;

    s = poly(0,parameter.string);
    h = syslin(dom.string,num,den);

    // Plotting of model data
    delete(gca());
    //bode(h,fmin1,fmax1);

    gain_axes = newaxes();
    gain_axes.title.font_size = 3;
    gainplot(h,fmin,fmax);
    gain_axes.axes_bounds = [1/3,0,1/3,1/2];
    gain_axes.title.text = "Gain Plot"; 
    phase_axes = newaxes();
    gain_axes.title.font_size = 3;
    phaseplot(h,fmin,fmax);
    phase_axes.axes_bounds = [1/3,1/2,1/3,1/2];
    phase_axes.title.text = "Phase Plot";
    phase_axes = newaxes();
    gain_axes.title.font_size = 3;
    nyquist(h);
    phase_axes.axes_bounds = [2/3,0,1/3,1/2];
    phase_axes.title.text = "Nyquist Plot";

endfunction
```

There's something wrong when passing numerator and denominator to the function. The variable type doesn't match what syslin required. If I replace 'num' and 'den' with '1' and '(s+1)^3', everything worked quite well. Also if I try this line-by-line in control panel, it works, but not in SciNotes. What's the proper way to deal with this? Any suggestion will be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 errors in your code: Replace

```
param.den = "(s+1)^3";  //denominator
```

with

```
param.den = (%s+1)^3;
```

Indeed, Scilab has a built-in polynomial type. Polynomials are not defined as a string nor as a vector of coefficients. The predefined constant `%s` is the monomial `s`.

In addition,

```
s = poly(0,parameter.string);
```

is useless (and incorrect: `parameter` would work, while `parameter.string` won't since `parameter` has no string field: It IS the string). Just remove the line.

As well, replace

```
h = syslin(dom.string,num,den);
```

with simply

```
h = syslin(dom, num,den);
```

Finally, although the figure's layout is not simple, you can use bode() in the function in the following way:

```
// delete(gca());
subplot(1,3,2)
bode(h, fmin, fmax)

subplot(2,3,3)
nyquist(h)

gcf().children.title.text=["Nyquist Plot"  "Phase Plot"  "Gain Plot"]
```

All in one, the code of your function may resume to

```
function displayProblem(param)
   [dom, num, den] = (param.dom,  param.num,  param.den);
   [fmin, fmax] = (param.fmin, param.fmax);

    h = syslin(dom, num,den);

    // Plotting of model data
    subplot(1,3,2)
    bode(h,fmin,fmax);

    subplot(2,3,3)
    nyquist(h);

    gcf().children.title.text=["Nyquist Plot" "Phase Plot" "Gain Plot"];
endfunction
```

Best regards

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your suggestions. I've tried using '%s' instead of 's', and removed 's = poly(...)'. These worked well. When I tried 'h = syslin(dom,num,den)', it kept warning me the wrong type for dom, num and den. Using 'dom.string' kind of helped building the plot, but 'num' and 'den' still got warning for wrong type. Your suggetions worked pretty well in control penal, but not in SciNotes. I agree that parameter and dom should be string, and I'm confused why this won't work...

Comment: Irene Z, Which Scilab's version are you using (type --> getversion // in the console)? By the way, could you please post the full actual "warning" message, about "it kept warning me the wrong type for dom, num and den"? Thanks

Comment: And please post the result of --> `param.dom, param.num, param.den` to see what is in it.

Comment: I used the version 6.1.1. If I put `h = syslin(dom,num,den);` as you suggested, the warning is **syslin: Wrong type for input argument #1: String, Scalar or empty matrix expected.**.

Comment: The result of `param.dom, param.num, param.den` is `ans  = "c", ans  =1. , ans  = 1 +3s +3s² +s³ `

Comment: And if you put `disp(dom, type(dom))` in the function just before `h = syslin(...`, exec the function to update it, and then call it as usual ; what then does it display? In brief, do the usual things to inspect and debug...